# Determining the area of a region

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm told the following:

`Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to x or y. Draw a typical approximating rectangle.`

For the following problem:

$$2x+y^2=48, x=y$$

I've just worked through about 3 of these area problems and this one really has me confused.  I've tried isolating one of the variables to get a function or $x$ or $y$, but this doesn't seem right as I don't know how this will help me to find the bounds.

I'm really confused as to how to get started on this one.

Comment: The curve is a "backward opening" parabola with axis of symmetry the $x$-axis. It mmets the line at $y=6$ and $y=-8$. You will find it easiest to integrate with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find solutions to both the equations or find the points where the curves intersect.

For that substitute $x=y$ into $2x+y^2=48$

The first curve is a parabola symmetric to the x-axis and the second is the identity function.

[image]

Comment: So I can just plug $x$ into the equation and and solve for $x$ that way?

Comment: Yes of course, by substituting x=y in the other equation you are finding the points where the curves will intersect and hence the common solutions. Anything else?

Comment: I think I understand!  I was getting confused by the variables being equal to one another.

Answer (score 2):

Does it help if you look at:

$$x = 24- y^2/2, x=y\quad?$$

The intersection points may be found by solving:
$$y^2+2y-48=0\quad\to \quad y=6,-8$$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: It does a little, but how do I determine the points of intersection from this?

Comment: I assume the axes are $x$ vertical, $y$ horizontal?

Comment: The graph should be telling the x and y axis. Please consider.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{-8}^{6}{\rm d}y
\int_{y}^{\left(24 - y^{2}\,/\,2\right)^{1\,/\,2}}\,{\rm d}x
$$